# Vue 3 array response from API doesn't mapping and foreach doesn't working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Here I have an array response and I want to mapping and take another array but I can't mapping and foreach is not working. Please see below code. I can see page_resp on console correctly. But comps variable is empty on console.

---

```js
const page_resp = reactive({ sections: [] })

fetch(APISettings.baseURL + 'Page/getcontent?pageId=1', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: APISettings.headers
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => (page_resp.sections = json.resultData?.sections))

console.log('page_resp', page_resp)

const comps = ref([])

page_resp.sections.map(comp => {
  comps.value.push(comp)
})
```

[console screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGOK8.png)

Comment: Yes, you need to wait until the request has finished

Comment: console logging objects can be deceiving.  if you are fetching some data and log it before the fetch is complete, the console will actually update to show the fetched data.  see the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects) about it.  Like Moritz said, wait for the request to finish: your mapping could be moved into a method, and you can call the method in the last `then()` of your fetch.  or you can just use async/await instead of then

Comment: thank you so much I use then() and solved